# How to handle app_command errors inside cogs? (discord.py)

Tags: error-handling, discord, discord.py, bots, python-decorators

I have a bot with cogs and app_commands mainly, I need an error handler and I have 2 requirements for it:

1. Send a message in chat or respond to the interaction with some error message
2. Not print an error textwall in the console, I don't want the console to be spammed with those, I'd like either nothing or a simple "this user tried to use this command" message.

So far I figured out that this works:

```py
    @app_commands.command(name="test", description="are u mod")
    @app_commands.checks.has_permissions(moderate_members=True)
    async def test(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("you are a mod!")

    @test.error
    async def test_error(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, error):
        print(f"{interaction.user} tried to use the `test` command")
        await interaction.response.send_message("no")
```

But the problem here is that I have to create such a `test_error` function for each admin command that I want to add. I'd like to have a global error handler for my app_commands instead. Something that does what `test_error` does, whenever any kind of "missing mod perms" check fails.

One additional thing I found was this:

```py
@bot.tree.error
async def on_app_command_error(interaction: discord.Interaction, error: app_commands.AppCommandError):
    if isinstance(error, app_commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        return await interaction.response.send_message(error, ephemeral = True)
    elif isinstance(error, app_commands.BotMissingPermissions):
        return await interaction.response.send_message(error, ephemeral = True)
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("An error occurred!", ephemeral = True)
        raise error
```

And... it satisfies the 1st requirement, kinda? It always just says "An error occured!", it never reaches the 1st or the 2nd case somehow. And it also doesn't solve the 2nd requirement, an error textwall is still sent in the console.

How can I handle errors and satisfy both of the requirements stated above?

In case you need more info about my bot, here's the basic structure:

main.py

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


async def load_cogs():
    for file in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if file.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{file[:-3]}')


asyncio.run(load_cogs())
bot.run(os.getenv('bot_key'))
```

examplecog.py:

```py
class example(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__ + " cog loaded")

    @app_commands.command(name="test", description="are u mod")
    @app_commands.checks.has_permissions(moderate_members=True)
    async def test(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("you are a mod!")


async def example(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(errors(bot))
```

Answer (score 3):

After a few hours of digging I found this solution:

```py
async def on_tree_error(interaction: discord.Interaction, error: app_commands.AppCommandError):
    if isinstance(error, app_commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        return await interaction.response.send_message(f"Command is currently on cooldown! Try again in **{error.retry_after:.2f}** seconds!")
    elif isinstance(error, app_commands.MissingPermissions):
        return await interaction.response.send_message(f"You're missing permissions to use that")
    else:
        raise error

bot.tree.on_error = on_tree_error
```

I added it to my `main.py` file, near the end.

That's all that is needed for error handling app commands. Simpler than I thought, better than I thought, but also extremely hard to find. Almost anywhere I looked I saw either my 1st solution, or "it's impossible in discord.py".

Who knows maybe in the future someone else will need that and will find this. Enjoy!